# xcode-select -switch doesn't work: active developer path does not exist

Tags: macos, xcode5

I have installed Xcode 5 developer preview 3. Before it i had developer preview 2 and now, sometimes in my terminal I see error, for example when I try to autocomplete some commands by tab:

```
error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select to change
```

I try to change this directory by executing command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer
```

Now xcode has correct path because command

```
sudo xcode-select -print-path
```

shows me result:

```
 /Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer
```

but I still see the same error in terminal, see attached: https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/120Z1S0b1Q302w3J453U/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-24%20at%2016.34.23.png?v=45e9961b

Comment: You cannot discuss that here I'm afraid until it's released.

Comment: It's a courtesy to the community to pick an accepted answer.

Answer (score 48):

It happened to me once: `xcode-select -print-path` did stick to the same value and wasn't changing. It appeared that it was always equal to DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable. According to the manpage of xcode-select:

> When DEVELOPER_DIR is set, its value will be used instead of the value
>   last passed to -switch xcode_path

So, unsetting DEVELOPER_DIR makes xcode-select -switch working.

Comment: correct, however the difference is that xcode-select will set the current location of the Xcode.app folder globally across all users. The DEVELOPER_DIR is merely an override as in any development environment, different users could be using different versions i.e. one developer may develop using Xcode 4.x for Mountain Lion and another on 5.x for Mavericks :)

Comment: `unset DEVELOPER_DIR` fixed it for me. Thanks

Comment: answer would be improved with the clear command to run `unset DEVELOPER_DIR`

Answer (score 33):

Try changing the path in xcode itself. [image]

Answer (score 3):

If you do a:

```
man xcode-select
```

It tells you to set the path with:

```
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-DP4.app
```

As I've just switched to DP4 to test. That worked for me. I didn't see it point to any of the .app contents. I guess this was probably changed from previous versions...

Answer (score 1):

If you are running beta release. Path should be look like this.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, space characters don't allow to take path correctly. So you may prefer to use \ character to include space into the path like below;

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode\ 10.2.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error after I change the name of Xcode app. I changed Xcode app to Xcode8.1.app. Then I run command

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode8.1.app/Contents/Developer
```

and now everything work as beginning.

Not sure are you in my case and your problem is solved or not. Maybe help another one.